# How to put tomcat7 always online?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat7

I have Ubuntu 14.04 cloud server with 512MB RAM on Digital Ocean and installed tomcat7 in order to accept my Java  applications, also there is a wordpress site running on it with little accesses. So, I created a REST Web Service that needs to always be online because there are accesses by Android Apps. The problem is when I don't use the WS for sometime it goes down and I have to manually start tomcat again.

When I ask for tomcat' status I have the answer below:

**Tomcat Servlet engine is not running, but pid file exists.**

Here is a memory log of server in normal state:

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       490        480          9         64          6        119
-/+ buffers/cache:    354        135
Swap:        0          0          0
```

Top command:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 8835 www-data  20   0  363904  65472  37244 S 16.6 13.0   0:31.02 php5-fpm
12625 www-data  20   0  361052  63896  35704 S  8.3 12.7   0:13.30 php5-fpm
24655 mysql     20   0  891176  56332   1576 S  1.7 11.2  72:04.31 mysqld
11509 www-data  20   0  361696  65796  37168 S  1.3 13.1   0:16.99 php5-fpm
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0   4:31.17 rcu_sched
   28 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0   0:44.41 kswapd0
  123 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0   3:26.29 jbd2/vda1-8
  744 www-data  20   0   91112   2400    540 S  0.3  0.5   0:53.93 nginx
13305 tomcat7   20   0 1126588 144516   5792 S  0.3 28.8   0:44.17 java
14557 root      20   0   24820   1508   1100 R  0.3  0.3   0:00.07 top
    1 root      20   0   33504   1504    120 S  0.0  0.3   1:59.18 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.83 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  0.0  0.0   4:37.10 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
```

Using the jmap -heap in tomcat process i have these details:

```
using thread-local object allocation.
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 134217728 (128.0MB)
   NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 44695552 (42.625MB)
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 174063616 (166.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 2424832 (2.3125MB)
   used     = 280872 (0.26786041259765625MB)
   free     = 2143960 (2.0446395874023438MB)
   11.583152977195946% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 2162688 (2.0625MB)
   used     = 242168 (0.23094940185546875MB)
   free     = 1920520 (1.8315505981445312MB)
   11.197546756628787% used
From Space:
   capacity = 262144 (0.25MB)
   used     = 38704 (0.0369110107421875MB)
   free     = 223440 (0.2130889892578125MB)
   14.764404296875% used
To Space:
   capacity = 262144 (0.25MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 262144 (0.25MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 34521088 (32.921875MB)
   used     = 26207256 (24.993186950683594MB)
   free     = 8313832 (7.928688049316406MB)
   75.91665708798054% used
Perm Generation:
   capacity = 50319360 (47.98828125MB)
   used     = 43680848 (41.65730285644531MB)
   free     = 6638512 (6.3309783935546875MB)
   86.8072407916158% used

16661 interned Strings occupying 2074936 bytes.
```

Does anybody know how to always put it online?

Comment: Probably you should look at something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223944/how-to-automatically-restart-tomcat7-on-system-reboots and you should look into process monitoring scripts, and maybe also run some cron job every few minutes that calls the webservice to check that the app is still alive and notify you if it fails.

Comment: Tomcat has no such timeout. There is a good chance your Tomcat JVM is crashing, especially based on the message you provided. Have a look at the Tomcat logs and see why the JVM might be crashing.

Comment: @jbx While that might "fix" the problem, it would be way better to figure out why Tomcat is dying in the first place. A cron job to restart tomcat periodically would not address the root problem whatsoever.

Comment: @rmlan Well from my experience with tomcat, its quite rare that tomcat just 'dies'. Its either the Digital Ocean VM got killed or restarted, in which case auto-restarting it when the VM is rebooted would solve the issue. If there is a problem with the code it won't die, it will just log exceptions in catalina.out etc. but the JVM process would still be running. The application would be unavailable (in which case the polling of the app would tell you something is wrong) and maybe then look at the exception in the logs and see what caused it.

Comment: I will put the tomcat online now and see what will happens on log and edit my post. But as @jbx said I don't think a cron will solve because it's go down always, less than a day, so the problem is bigger, maybe on tomcat or maybe on Digital Ocean VM.

Comment: @MarceloMachado is the Digital Ocean server being restarted? What do you get when you do `uptime` ? Also after you restart it and log off, log in again and check whether it is still up and running, in case its something to do with the shell killing it after you disconnect your session. Also did you install `tomcat7` via `apt-get` ?

Comment: How much memory are you allocating for the JVM?

Comment: @jbx My server doesn't restart, I have a wordpress site online in it. If I restart the tomcat this works fine and if I log off and log on it's online too, the problem happens after sometime, that I don't know exactly. Yes I installed by apt-get.

Comment: @GermanRosales My server has 512Mb Ram and I have a web site running in that, can be a problem about that? I put the server online Right now, when it go down I'll post here the log.

Comment: Did you set up swap space on the server? It sounds like it might be an issue if you're running Apache with PHP for Wordpress and also Tomcat. Are you also running a database on it? What memory usage do you get when you do `top`?

Comment: @MarceloMachado what about -Xms -Xmx -XX:MaxPermSize arguments? maybe you are using more memory than ram and swap actually provide?

Comment: @jbx I didn't set up the swap space, when I use the command grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo I had the answer 0kb. 
To use wordpress and my WS I need databases.

Comment: @GermanRosales I didn't set up the swap space.

Comment: Ooh, only 9MB free? Run "top", and sort by mem. usage to see which processes use how much memory. While tomcat is still running, also run  "jmap -heap " with the process id of the tomcat process, to see more details.

Comment: @greyfairer Done. I believe that could be the problem. Create a swap memory may help?

Comment: Tomcat probably gets killed by the out-of-memory killer - scan the `/var/log/syslog` file for OOM messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you have a 512 MB RAM server, and you have MySQL and PHP5 running, the JVM will probably have crashed with an OutOfMemory exception.

In the jmap output, the only important number is the free memory of the concurrent mark sweep generation, where you have only 7.9 MB free, which sounds very small for a web service.

Before it crashes, the JVM will also spend a lot of time trying to garbage collect, which could lead to the process becoming non-responsive, even before it crashes completely.

You could add 1GB of swap (IIRC, linux admins recommend swap = 2 x ram). 
See e.g. http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html for AWS, will probably work on Digital Ocean, too.

The MySQL and PHP5 processes can probably swap out a lot of unused allocated memory. If that slows your applications down too much, you'll probably need some more RAM, or move the PHP and MySQL to different servers.